# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

when is am trying to start my tomcat on unix server i am getting the following exception in catalina.out

> INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.37 Handler error
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
>           at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
>           at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:521)
>           at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:464)

Can anyone help resolving this?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have all libraries packaged in your application war. You need to put all slf4j libraries in the `WEB-INF\lib` directory of your application.

If your `webapp` directory is empty, then you probably configured Tomcat to use slf4j somehow. If that is the case then you need `jul-to-slf4j.jar` in Tomcat's `lib` directory. For your reference I've found the name of the library looking at [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/search/?query=org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler). You can download `jul-to-slf4j.jar` from [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.slf4j%7Cjul-to-slf4j%7C1.7.12%7Cjar).

If this is a fresh install of Tomcat, I would reinstall Tomcat, since it should not be behaving like that.